# reference map value in the same map (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am certain my issue here is not knowing what to call what I'm trying to do here, so any help with that would be appreciated, but I'd like to map over an array and create two values, where the first one refers to the prior value... is that possible?

```
arr =[1,2,3]
arr.map((el, i) => ({ 
   x: el, 
   y: 5, 
   z: y[i] + 2 // is there a way I can write this so I can refer to y ???
}))
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: How is the `y` generated?

Comment: There is a syntax error in the example. `) ({ ` probably should be `) => ({ `

Comment: @HaoWu I think adding the iterator makes it clearer, I'm creating the 5 value for each item in the array and want to use each of those... hope that makes sense!

Comment: You are already referring to `y`. what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: You have initialized `y` as an integer primitive value - what do you expect the `[]` to do for you? What do you want to do with "refer to `y`"?

Comment: Really unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: The answer is _NO_. You cannot access a property within the midst of an assignment statement that is also a part of the (unassigned) assignment statement. Your goal will take two operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

const newArr = arr.map((currentValue, currentIndex) => {
  const previousValue = currentIndex > 0 ? arr[currentIndex - 1] : 0

  const output = {
    x: currentValue,
    y: 5,
    z: previousValue + 2
  }

  return output
})
```

Comment: Oh, guess what actually OP wanted is to access the value from the previous iteration